# Error: entitled_product_ids:expected Hash to be a Array (Shopify embedded app)

Tags: php, shopify

I am sending the following request through cURL, all is going fine but there is an error with "entitled_product_id". It works fine in postman but not in cURL.

Thanks in advance.

**cURL request code is**

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $access_token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($pro_ids11));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Shopify-Access-Token: '.$shops_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
if (isset($error_msg)) {
    echo $error_msg;
}
```

**My json_encoded code is:**

```
{
  "price_rule":
  {
    "title":"sad",
    "target_type":"line_item",
    "target_selection":"entitled",
    "allocation_method":"across",
    "value_type":"percentage",
    "value":"-3",
    "customer_selection":"all",
    "prerequisite_quantity_range":{"greater_than_or_equal_to":"2"},
    "entitled_product_ids":["2389482225165"],
    "starts_at":"2019-02-20T11:37:57.000Z"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "errors":
    {
      "entitled_product_ids":"expected Hash to be a Array"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you send `"entitled_product_ids":[2389482225165],` (without the quotes)?

Comment: no, It is with quotes, I've also provided decoded code above. @cbaconnier

Comment: There's no quotes on the documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/discounts/pricerule#create

Comment: I've tried without quotes too. but did not work :/